# Database Server Can't Find 300GB

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, hard-drive

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.  I have some how lost 300 GB of disk space, and I can't seem to find it anywhere.  The Hard Drive is 500GB and I can only account for 200GB.  I have "Show Hidden Files" on and "Hide Protected Files" off.  I have check the details for every folder top level folder, and I still can only find 200 GB of a 500 GB Hard Disk.  The disk is almost full and this doesn't make any sense.  Any one have any ideas of where I might be able to find this lost space?  On a weekly basis I delete old back ups of the databases.  Maybe that might have something to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Windirstat](http://windirstat.info/).  It'll give you a graphical view of your disk space usage, as well as sort your folders by space used.  A lot easier than trying to hunt through Windows Explorer for what's chewing up your disk space.

Comment: That is really interesting, Explorer says that Program Files is only 1.13 GB.  When I ran this program it is saying that it is actually 362 GB, that is all the space that I can't account for.  I will now be talking with our database people to see what the issue is.  Thanks for your help, it was greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If one doesn't fix it, try the next:

1. Run `chkdsk` against the disk.
2. Run `vssadmin list shadows` to see if there are any volume snapshots.
3. Run a program that can list directory sizes, such as Winstatdir listed by HopelessN00b.

Comment: +1 I would bet it's shadow storage using the space